# Edit/Print <input> field via Console

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have. Nothing has IDs, Names or Classes.

Is there anyway to enter a vaue in the input field under City using the Chrome Console and js? Alternatively is there a way I can print the value of said field also using js in the Chrome Console?

I assume it requires using the div City and traversing to next input.

Thanks ahead of time!

```
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div>Address</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div>City</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div>Zipcode</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks.. i'm asking how to fill a form through the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boilerplate code

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
try {
    var field = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent;
    if (field == "City") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "your values"
    }
} catch (err) {}
}
```

Comment: try again with above one

Comment: hmm, now getting tables not defined... thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: What you mean tables not defined ? It's defined in first line itself .Open your file in browser . just paste the above snippet and you should see it working .

Comment: ah the var tables line didnt show previously sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to pull the same value and print it to the console?

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName("table")[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="your value"

Comment: This works, however would there be a way to find the element based on the word city? as there could be more/less tables. Thanks!

Comment: @user2623720 could you [add this to your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53226686/edit) rather than as a comment? Code in the comments looks ugly and might get missed.